# Como convertir de png a bmp

Tags: c#

como puedo convertir una imagen png a bmp desde c# 
He intentado con esto:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/a/test.png");
Stream originalBinaryDataStream = new MemoryStream(data);
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(originalBinaryDataStream);
image.Save(@"C:/a/image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
originalBinaryDataStream.Dispose();
```

Me da error me sale la imagen bmp negra y ademas me dice A generic error occurred in GDI+

Al ejecutar el codigo me muestra esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrias usar

```
string imgPng = @"C:\a\test.png";
string imgBmp = @"C:\a\image.bmp";

Image png = Image.FromFile(imgPng);
png.Save(imgBmp , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
png.Dispose();
```

puedes cargar las imagenes directamente desde la ruta, no necesitas el byte array

Comment: me guarda la imagen negra, adjuntare la imagen de lo que me crea el codigo

Comment: Ya veo cual es es problema aqui, es que el png que estoy creando anteriormente esta corrupto, es que tengo una imagen dentro de un canvas en html y esa imagen la necesito en bmp